# Setting telerik date picker value using jquery

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik date picker control in the razor view as below :

`@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m=>m.SalesOrganizationProfile.EffectiveDate)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "profileEffectiveDateEditSection" })`

How do I set the value of this using jquery.
`$('#profileEffectiveDateEditSection').val("1/1/2012")` does not work.

Any help on this is appreciated. This razor view is in ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is :

@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.EffectiveDate).Name("profileEffectiveDate");

and then use code from Pechka".

var datepicker = $('#profileEffectiveDate').data('tDatePicker');
datepicker.value(new Date('1/1/2012'));

Note: I had to use Name property instead of ID(Even though I dont know why id does not work)

Answer (score 1):

Value should be set through the value method of the client object. [Here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-datepicker-client-api-and-events.html#ClientMethods) is part of the documentation which covers it.

```
var datepicker = $('#profileEffectiveDateEditSection').data('tDatePicker');
datepicker.value(new Date('1/1/2012'));
```

Comment: This helped + i had to change my initialization to have the "Name" property instead of id. I thought id was the way to access the control, however it is the name